# Oracle JDBC Java9

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-9

Как-то можно подружить JDBC драйвер к 12 Ораклу и Java9? Я использую ojdbc и ucp и при компиляции получаю кучу ошибок вида

> Error:java: the unnamed module reads package oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime from both ojdbc8 and ucp

Пакет `oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime`, действительно, существует в обоих jar файлах

Comment: Если запустить приложение через class path, то должно всё работать. Второй вариант - слить ojdbc и ucp в одну джарку.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Как слить? Просто раззиповать и зазиповать обратно?

Comment: Ну да, только конечно не факт, что после этого выйдет валидная джарка. Так что я бы сначала попробовал всё запустить через classpath, это точно решит проблему.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov я правильно понимаю, что при этом приложение запускаться будет, но при этом IDE ничего не будет знать об этих пакетах и соответственно никаких подсказок?

Comment: Почему? IDE же умеет парсить jar-файлы и доставать оттуда информацию о классах, методах и т.д. А вот Javadoc да, будет отсутствовать, если ничего не сделать. Но можно и source джарку тоже сделать путём слияния. Тогда всё будет ОК.